# How to break a loop from a check in discord.py Python?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
async def blabla(ctx):
    async def unmute():
        unmuted = await ctx.send('A Message Here')

        await unmuted.add_reaction('\U0001F508') #Emoji One
        await unmuted.add_reaction('\U0001F503') #Emoji Two

        def check(reaction, user):
            return (user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) == '\U0001F508') or reaction.count >= 3
        await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check) 
        # When Emoji one detected, continue.
        # When Emoji two detected, break the loop inside the main function.

        await ctx.send('Emoji One Detected')
    
    while True:
        await start()
        while True: # When Emoji Two is detected, I want to break this and go to previous loop.
            await unmute()
            await mute()
```

I'm stuck on this for a while now, have tried a couple ways but the program still doesn't work like I want it to. Essentially Emoji Two is like a restart button where if pressed, it will break the loop and go to the previous loop where `await start()` is at.

Any ideas? :s

Comment: you can make your `unmute` method return `True` or `False`. Wrap it in an `if` condition and do a `break` there. That cancels the inner `while` loop.

Comment: That works thanks! Now my question is, is there a better way to implement this. How I'm doing it now is I have like 3 nested functions and then a small "While True, try" in the parent function. @TinNguyen